# Receptive field size of VGG16

Tags: neural-network

As posted in the title I am not able to understand how numerically calculate the receptive field size of VGG16. I have read a lot of articles on the internet. I got the formula and so on, but I really can't apply these recursive formula with calculation of receptive field of `VGG16`.

1 `Conv N=64;Filter size=3x3;padding=1,striding=1 receptive field size = 212`

2 `ReLU Receptive field size = 210`

3 `Conv N=64;Filter size=3x3;padding=1,striding=1 receptive field size = 212`

These are the results. My questions are:

- Why receptive field size is 212? Can you make a calculation by hand to make it more clear?
- Why `relu` change receptive field size?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You get the size of the previous layer (`ReLU`), which is 210, include `padding=1` -- this means 1 pixel on every side, so `210 + 1 + 1 = 212`, quite simple, actually...

If you want to understand "receptive field", read section 7.2 of the document the link to which you have provided in the comments. It clearly says: "A 3 × 3 convolution layer will increase the receptive field by 2 and a pooling
layer will double the spatial extent." -- so they start from a single pixel for the bottom layer, and go up, increasing receptive field according to the before mentioned rule, doubling the size in case of pooling and adding pixels in case of the convolution.

Comment: Ok, clear. Do you have an answer for the first question?

Comment: @Cesc I don't know where you've got your layer descriptions. VGG16/VGG19 as well as many other CNN participants of the ImageNet contest use 224x224 images as input -- that's pretty standard among all of them, because the dataset images have that resolution.

Comment: So?What changes in the calcuation of receptive field size? i know the size of the input of vgg16

Comment: @Cesc did you read page 31, section 7.2 titled 'receptive field' that talks about receptive field calculation?? which part of section 7.2 did you not understand?